# JQuery animated always image

Tags: jquery, slide

from http://felixplus.com/demo/boom/wp/

I want to animated cloud same this.

How do I do for animated cloud ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure css is enough to achieve.

```
.cloud{
    background:#404 url('http://felixplus.com/demo/boom/wp/wp-content/themes/boom/images/background/1.png') repeat-x left bottom;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    animation: animatingCloud 30s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatingCloud 30s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatingCloud{
    from{
        background-position: left bottom;
    }
    to{
        background-position: right bottom;
    }
}
@keyframes animatingCloud{
    from{
        background-position: left bottom;
    }
    to{
        background-position: right bottom;
    }
}
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/EgHmQ/1/

Comment: -o-animation,-moz-animation when necessary